# RPi3 with 22.04.x LTS wont boot after upgrading packages/kernel

Tags: 22.04, raspberrypi, reboot

I imaged a USB stick to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS , via the official RPi image..

I successfully started up the image and logged in on this pi.. which is a RPi3 ..

However, I go to perform a `apt update && apt upgrade -y` .. and it says the upgrade of the kernel will not happen automatically and I need to reboot.. okay..

so I shutdown, unplug, replugin the pi... the lights blink but I never get any HDMI output on the screen at all.. seems like the upgrade borked everything and I am unsure how to recover .. if it's even possible.

EDIT: incase it's not clear.. I am booting off the USB stick, not the SD card.. everything works fine with rasbpian images but would prefer to get ubuntu server 22.04

Comment: You ask about kernel but did not include the kernel info in your question. What kernel are you using?

Comment: 5.15 I think.. it's whatever defaults on latest upgrade.. I may wipe the USB stick and try again.. will make note of exact version if/when I do

Comment: 22.04 LTS ISO now defaults to the 5.19 Kernel.  You can find out what Kernel version you have with the `uname -a` or `uname -r` commands.